# Saga 2.3.2 fill sink

Tags: qgis, saga, fill

I am trying to run the saga fill sinks (wang &liu) but it always results in following error
"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs' See log for more details".  I am using QGIS 2.18.12. I am running this algorithm inside QGIS.

I do not know what i am doing wrong

Raster CRS is "+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs". I have projected it before running the fill sink(wang & liu).

Comment: 'crs' is the acronym of Coordinate Reference System. Does your raster have this attribute? Check on properties window, if not, define projection to solve this issue

Comment: are you running this from inside QGIS (using Processing)? Have you tried the equivalent command (saga_cmd) from a terminal (osgeo4w shell on Windows), or from the saga gui? Also what version of QGIS?

Comment: "+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs" i have projected it before running the fill sink(wang & liu)

Comment: @StevenKay, I am using QGIS 2.18.12. I am running this algorithm inside QGIS.

Comment: If you are using standalone QGIS, is it possible to update it to QGIS 2.18.14? I think SAGA 2.3.2 is better aligned with 2.18.14. Or, if you need to stay with QGIS 2.18.12, SAGA 2.1.2 - 2.1.4 would be safer.

Comment: @Kazuhito, i tried, but the same problem still exists. what else can i try?

Comment: @StevenKay, can u please suggest how to use processing from osgeo4w shell on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Namitha and sorry about that. Only remaining "check-point" I can think of is the path to your raster file; that there should be no spaces, no non-ascii characters... If it does not work, try OSGeo4W shell suggested by @StevenKay.

Comment: @Kazuhito, i have checked the file name, there is no space and no non-ascii characters in my raster file. it would be of great help if u can run me through steps to do processing in osgeo4w shell.

Comment: Is this a problem due to projection or resolution of DEM image?

Comment: @Namitha I could not reproduce this. So I have googled with 'NoneType' error + 'crs' (there were not many) about SAGA on QGIS, but could not find solved cases (even using OSGeo4W shell). Sorry. I recommend to use SAGA GUI (which is likely free from this issue) or GRASS r.fill.dir...

Comment: @Kazuhito, i will mail you the the DEM Images if you would like to try,let me   know your decision.

Comment: @Namitha I think we'd better solve issues in a way future readers can also benefit from this site. To discern root cause you can test the workflow using a small sample data, for instance, one available in QGIS documentation [1.1.7 Data](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/foreword/foreword.html#data).

Comment: Is there a water shed area limit to use saga fill sink command?